# How to list tables affected by cascading delete

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I'm trying to perform a cascading delete on 15+ tables but I'm not certain that all of the requisite foreign keys have been configured properly.  I would like to check for missing constraints without manually reviewing each constraint.

Is there a way to obtain a list of tables that will be affected by a cascading delete query?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use [`pg_depend`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/catalog-pg-depend.html). Example:

```
create table master (id int primary key);
create table detail_1 (id int, master_id int references master(id) on delete restrict);
create table detail_2 (id int, master_id int references master(id) on delete cascade);

select pg_describe_object(classid, objid, objsubid)
from pg_depend 
where refobjid = 'master'::regclass and deptype = 'n';

                  pg_describe_object
------------------------------------------------------
 constraint detail_1_master_id_fkey on table detail_1
 constraint detail_2_master_id_fkey on table detail_2
(2 rows)
```

`deptype = 'n'` means:

> DEPENDENCY NORMAL - A normal relationship between separately-created
>   objects. The dependent object can be dropped without affecting the
>   referenced object. The referenced object can only be dropped by
>   specifying CASCADE, in which case the dependent object is dropped,
>   too.

Use [`pg_get_constraintdef()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-info.html) to get constraint definitions:

```
select 
    pg_describe_object(classid, objid, objsubid), 
    pg_get_constraintdef(objid)
from pg_depend 
where refobjid = 'master'::regclass and deptype = 'n';


                  pg_describe_object                  |                       pg_get_constraintdef
------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 constraint detail_1_master_id_fkey on table detail_1 | FOREIGN KEY (master_id) REFERENCES master(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
 constraint detail_2_master_id_fkey on table detail_2 | FOREIGN KEY (master_id) REFERENCES master(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
(2 rows)
```

---

To find the full chain of cascading dependencies we should use recursion and look into the catalog `pg_constraint` to get `id` of a dependent table.

```
with recursive chain as (
    select classid, objid, objsubid, conrelid
    from pg_depend d
    join pg_constraint c on c.oid = objid
    where refobjid = 'the_table'::regclass and deptype = 'n'
union all
    select d.classid, d.objid, d.objsubid, c.conrelid
    from pg_depend d
    join pg_constraint c on c.oid = objid
    join chain on d.refobjid = chain.conrelid and d.deptype = 'n'
    )
select pg_describe_object(classid, objid, objsubid), pg_get_constraintdef(objid)
from chain;
```

Comment: Thanks this was a huge help!  However these queries only show the direct child FKs not the full chain of cascading deletes.  So to find all of the tables affected by a delete I have to run this query again on every distinct table name returned for each execution.  This is time consuming for databases with complex table relationships.

Comment: Try the recursive version of the query.

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: Thank you, this was the only thing that worked to show me what dependencies a table had!

Answer (score 8):

Yes. you can truncate cascade in transaction and rollback. Note `ROLLBACK` is a key to save the data.
postgres will `NOTICE` you what other referencing tables will be affected.

```
postgres=# begin;
BEGIN
postgres=# truncate table a cascade;
NOTICE:  truncate cascades to table "b"
TRUNCATE TABLE
postgres=# rollback;
ROLLBACK
```

Comment: In the case the OP is asking about, you can see the plan that actually gets executed by the delete via `begin; explain analyze <delete query>; rollback;`. Note that you are executing the actual query, then rolling back the results.

Answer (score 8):

Using transitive closure, one can determine the referencing and referenced tables. A caveat is that this query/view depends on the existence of Foreign Keys to determine the dependencies, and will *not* find tables if the FK's are missing (and the latter seems to be what the OP is asking for).

#### Table dependencies via Foreign Keys

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW table_dependencies AS (
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
    SELECT
        c.oid AS origin_id,
        c.oid::regclass::text AS origin_table,
        c.oid AS referencing_id,
        c.oid::regclass::text AS referencing_table,
        c2.oid AS referenced_id,
        c2.oid::regclass::text AS referenced_table,
        ARRAY[c.oid::regclass,c2.oid::regclass] AS chain
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint AS co
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class AS c ON c.oid = co.conrelid
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class AS c2 ON c2.oid = co.confrelid
--     Add this line as an input parameter if you want to make a one-off query
--     WHERE c.oid::regclass::text = 'YOUR TABLE'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.origin_id,
        t.origin_table,
        t.referenced_id AS referencing_id,
        t.referenced_table AS referencing_table,
        c3.oid AS referenced_id,
        c3.oid::regclass::text AS referenced_table,
        t.chain || c3.oid::regclass AS chain
    FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint AS co
    INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class AS c3 ON c3.oid = co.confrelid
    INNER JOIN t ON t.referenced_id = co.conrelid
    WHERE
        -- prevent infinite recursion by pruning paths where the last entry in
        -- the path already appears somewhere else in the path
        NOT (
            ARRAY[ t.chain[array_upper(t.chain, 1)] ] -- an array containing the last element
            <@                                        -- "is contained by"
            t.chain[1:array_upper(t.chain, 1) - 1]    -- a slice of the chain,
                                                      -- from element 1 to n-1
        )
)
SELECT  origin_table,
        referenced_table,
        array_upper(chain,1) AS "depth",
        array_to_string(chain,',') as chain
FROM t
);
```

#### Tables referencing a specific table

```
SELECT * FROM table_dependencies WHERE origin_table = 'clients';
```

#### Tables directly related to the "clients" table

```
SELECT *
FROM table_dependencies
WHERE referenced_table = 'clients'
AND depth = 2
ORDER BY origin_table;
```