# POSTGRES - Risk of dropping foreign data wrapper/schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, cascade

We had one of the devs create a foreign data wrapper with these commands:

```
CREATE SERVER serverName FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (xxxx);
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR user SERVER foreign_db OPTIONS (user 'xxxx', password 'xxxx');
CREATE SCHEMA foreign_db;
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public FROM SERVER serverName INTO foreign_db;
```

To drop this schema the suggestion was to run:

```
DROP SCHEMA if exists foreign_db cascade;
DROP USER mapping if exists for user server foreign_db;
DROP SERVER if exists serverName;
```

In the spec I see this for CASCADE:

> Automatically drop objects (tables, functions, etc.) that are
>   contained in the schema, and in turn all objects that depend on those
>   objects

what concerns me is this line:

```
and in turn all objects that depend on those objects
```

My question is there a possibility of dropping anything outside of **foreign_db** schema and if yes, how can I check it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that the command drops *something* outside the schema. Consider this:

```
create schema example;
create table example.my_table (id int);
create view public.my_view as select * from example.my_table;
```

If the schema is dropped with the cascade option, `public.my_view` will also be dropped. However, the behavior is logical and desirable.

You can check this executing these commands one by one:

```
begin;
drop schema example cascade;
rollback;
```

The schema will not be dropped and after `drop...` you should get something like this:

```
NOTICE:  drop cascades to 2 other objects
DETAIL:  drop cascades to table example.my_tabledrop cascades to view my_view
```

Alternatively, you can use the system catalog `pg_depend`, see this answer [How to list tables affected by cascading delete.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37977656/1995738)