# Which tables, triggers, views are affected by a drop column cascade in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, migration, alter

Django created a migration for dropping a field from a table:

```
ALTER TABLE "my_table" DROP COLUMN "my_deprecated_field" CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

I would like to know which consquences the `CASCADE` has, i.e. which other columns, tables, triggers, etc. are going to be affected by it.

Since there is no `EXPLAIN ALTER`, which other means do I have to find out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37976832/how-to-list-tables-affected-by-cascading-delete

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll remove all the objects which are dependent or having reference(foreign key, etc) to this object too.

Assume `Table A` is having non-nullable foreign key to `Table B`.

If someone drops `Table B`, what will happen to `Table A` ? Table A rows will point to what ? It can't point to null, as it's non-nullable.

`CASCASE` come into picture here and using it on `Table B` will lead to dropping off of `Table A` rows also.

You can see a example here http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-drop-column/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to get a full list of things that are going to be removed. I read the documenation, but I do not know which parts of my database exactly will be affected.

Comment: This is false. The depend objects are the **constraints**, not the rows. `Table A` will keep all its data, but the field that was referring to `Table B` will not be referring to anything anymore