# How to find all object which will be dropped by CASCADE?

Tags: postgresql, cascade

When I `DROP` something like this

```
ALTER TABLE "order_bt" DROP COLUMN "billed_to"
```

the command will list dependencies of the `billed_to` column:

```
DETAIL:  view "order" depends on column billed_to of table order_bt
```

But, this view `order` also has associated triggers, which would also be dropped when adding `CASCADE` to the above `DROP` command.

Is there an option that will allow me to see the full list of what would be dropped with `DROP ... CASCADE`?

Comment: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37977656/15424227) can help you.

Comment: @nachospiu: Thank you. But accepted answer does not show that some triggers depend on my view for "order"

Comment: You are welcome! Read: "To find the full chain of cascading dependencies we should use recursion...". I think you will need to modify the query, but it will show you the way. You can read [pg_trigger doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html).

Comment: @nachospiu: I run exactly that query (changing 'the_table' by 'order' before), and get no info back. Anyway thank you for links, I will read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an example structure to check dependencies. You can try it on your database, of course objects ID will be different.

```
CREATE TABLE parents (
  id_parent integer NOT NULL,
  name_parent varchar(100),
  CONSTRAINT pk_parents_id PRIMARY KEY (id_parent)
);

CREATE TABLE childs (
  id_child integer NOT NULL,
  name_child varchar(100),
  parent_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_childs_id PRIMARY KEY (id_child),
  CONSTRAINT fk_childs_parent_id__parents FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
      REFERENCES parents (id_parent) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.parents_view AS 
 SELECT parents.id_parent,
    parents.name_parent
   FROM parents;

CREATE FUNCTION test_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' then
        raise notice 'INSERT trigger, NEW = [%]', NEW;
    ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE' then
        raise notice 'UPDATE trigger, OLD = [%], NEW = [%]', OLD, NEW;
    ELSE
        raise notice 'DELETE trigger, OLD = [%]', OLD;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER parents_view_trigger INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON parents_view FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_trigger();
```

Objects that depend of table "parents":

```
SELECT 
    refclassid, refobjid, refobjsubid,
    pg_describe_object(refclassid, refobjid, refobjsubid), 
    --pg_identify_object (refclassid, refobjid, refobjsubid) ,

    classid, objid, objsubid,
    pg_describe_object(classid, objid, objsubid), 
    --pg_identify_object (classid, objid, objsubid) ,
    pg_get_constraintdef(objid),

    deptype
    
FROM pg_depend 
WHERE refobjid IN ('parents'::regclass) -- and deptype IN ('n', 'a')
ORDER BY classid, refobjid;
```

Output:

| refclassid | refobjid | refobjsubid | pg_describe_object refobject | classid | objid | objsubid | pg_describe_object object | pg_get_constraintdef | deptype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1259 | 2305241 | 0 | table parents | 1247 | 2305243 | 0 | type parents |  | i |
| 1259 | 2305241 | 1 | table parents column id_parent | 2606 | 2305245 | 0 | constraint pk_parents_id on table parents | PRIMARY KEY (id_parent) | a |
| 1259 | 2305241 | 1 | table parents column id_parent | 2606 | 2305251 | 0 | constraint fk_childs_parent_id__parents on table childs | FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parents(id_parent) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE | n |
| 1259 | 2305241 | 1 | table parents column id_parent | 2618 | 2305259 | 0 | rule _RETURN on view parents_view |  | n |
| 1259 | 2305241 | 2 | table parents column name_parent | 2618 | 2305259 | 0 | rule _RETURN on view parents_view |  | n |

Objects that depend of view "parents_view":

```
SELECT 
    refclassid, refobjid, refobjsubid,
    pg_describe_object(refclassid, refobjid, refobjsubid), 
    --pg_identify_object (refclassid, refobjid, refobjsubid),

    classid, objid, objsubid,
    pg_describe_object(classid, objid, objsubid), 
    --pg_identify_object (classid, objid, objsubid) ,
    pg_get_constraintdef(objid),

    deptype
    
FROM pg_depend 
WHERE refobjid IN ('parents_view'::regclass) -- and deptype IN ('n', 'a')
ORDER BY classid, refobjid;
```

Output:

| refclassid | refobjid | refobjsubid | pg_describe_object refobj | classid | objid | objsubid | pg_describe_object obj | pg_get_constraintdef | deptype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1259 | 2305256 | 0 | view parents_view | 1247 | 2305258 | 0 | type parents_view |  | i |
| 1259 | 2305256 | 0 | view parents_view | 2618 | 2305259 | 0 | rule _RETURN on view parents_view |  | i |
| 1259 | 2305256 | 0 | view parents_view | 2618 | 2305259 | 0 | rule _RETURN on view parents_view |  | n |
| 1259 | 2305256 | 0 | view parents_view | 2620 | 2305260 | 0 | trigger parents_view_trigger on view parents_view |  | a |

You can check that view "parents_view" (object ID: 2305256) not depend of table parents but rule "rule _RETURN on view parents_view" (object ID: 2305259) does, and "trigger parents_view_trigger on view parents_view" depends on parents_view, this is the reason why recursive query do not return view dependent information.

Triggers are DEPENDENCY_AUTO type (a): The dependent object can be dropped separately from the referenced object, and should be automatically dropped (regardless of RESTRICT or CASCADE mode) if the referenced object is dropped. Example: a named constraint on a table is made auto-dependent on the table, so that it will go away if the table is dropped.

You can try a query like this, but you should try to improve it:

You can restrict the result filtering by deptype.

```
WITH RECURSIVE pg_depend_recursive AS (
                SELECT d.refclassid, d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid, d.classid, d.objid, d.objsubid, d.deptype
                FROM pg_depend d
                where refobjid = 'parents'::regclass

                UNION

                SELECT d.refclassid, d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid, d.classid, d.objid, d.objsubid, d.deptype
                FROM pg_depend d
                INNER JOIN pg_depend_recursive dr ON d.refobjid = dr.objid),

        pg_depend_recursive2 AS (SELECT d.refclassid, d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid, d.classid, d.objid, d.objsubid, d.deptype 
                    FROM pg_depend_recursive d

                    UNION

                    SELECT d.refclassid, d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid, d.classid, d.objid, d.objsubid, d.deptype
                    FROM pg_depend d
                    INNER JOIN pg_depend_recursive2 dr ON d.objid = dr.objid AND pg_describe_object(dr.classid, dr.objid, dr.objsubid) ilike 'rule%'),
                    
        pg_depend_recursive3 AS (SELECT d.refclassid, d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid, d.classid, d.objid, d.objsubid, d.deptype 
                    FROM pg_depend_recursive2 d

                    UNION

                    SELECT d.refclassid, d.refobjid, d.refobjsubid, d.classid, d.objid, d.objsubid, d.deptype
                    FROM pg_depend d
                    INNER JOIN pg_depend_recursive3 dr ON d.refobjid = dr.refobjid)
                    
SELECT refclassid, refobjid, refobjsubid, pg_describe_object(refclassid, refobjid, refobjsubid),
       classid, objid, objsubid, pg_describe_object(classid, objid, objsubid),
       deptype
FROM pg_depend_recursive3;
```

Comment: Works fine. But to note, it cannot list objects (like RLS policies) dependent on a function.